# Simultaneously modify multiple image frames in scribus

Tags: pdf

I am creating a directory-like book with scribus. It has people's names, addresses and images.

I can create text-frames and assign them a paragraph style (ex: address). And as long as I ensure that all addresses share the same paragraph style, it is easy to modify them all at one go.

Is something similar possible with image frames? I created them with a particular height and width and want to change them to another.

NOTE: This is a question about scribus but since scribus is not yet an allowed tag, am tagging it as PDF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible with a small Python script that runs inside of Scribus.

You can go through all image frames and

- check for their width and height to see if they match the "master" one and change them, or
- set the frame's name to start with a specific string and match it with a pattern.

You can get some inspiration from this script

https://github.com/aoloe/scribus-script-repository/tree/master/sync-matching-text-frame

that introduces a poor man's "patterns" for 1.4.

If you have no Python skills, I can help you with the script. (I will prepare a draft for it and let you debug it : - )

And, concerning the #scribus tag: there is one in https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ ...

Comment: Thank you. I'll explore this further myself. Have always wanted to learn Python.

Comment: Nice! You can come (back) to the irc channel if you have questions... and don't forget to publish here (or make by making a pull request with a new script to my "inofficial" scribus script collection :-) the result!

Answer (score 0):

Answer from @plinnell on scribus's IRC

"The quality is likely to be highly variable. I would batch resize outside of Scribus and then import at 100% scale after the resize"